# WPF and MVVM. Binding Events

Tags: wpf, events, mvvm, binding, icommand

I'm developing a WPF application with the MVVM pattern, RelayCommand, etc.
I read a lot on this question but I am not clear as to:

All I want to do is move a shape, like an ellipse, for example, and capture its final position, to put in the database.

But I can't bind events (MouseLetButtonDown, MouseLeftButtonUp and MouseMove) to commands.  I've read about attached behaviours , but I need the arguments of the events (MouseButtonEventArgs and MouseEventArgs) to retrieve the position.

Solution?

Answer (score 8):

When writing an MVVM graphical application, it is tempting to try to send all the events you need over to the view-model.  But processing view-specific mouse event args in a command is contrary to MVVM principles and the goal of loose-coupling.

The way to solve this problem is to abstract the operation into a task that the view can perform and then to communicate its results back to the view-model via operations and data.  If you want to perform a small amount of code in the code-behind to support this, the MVVM police will not come and take your children.  But an even better way is to add interactivity with behaviors.  Behaviors are re-usable pieces of functionality with no code-behind that work well with the MVVM pattern and applications that need interactivity that would otherwise require adding event handlers to your XAML.

See my answer here for a complete example of a behavior that uses mouse events for dragging graphical objects:

- [Coach a newbie through basic WPF? (I Do Not Grok It.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4768029/coach-a-newbie-through-basic-wpf-i-do-not-grok-it/4771503#4771503)

With your interactivity performed by the view, the view-model can stick to data and commands.

Comment: Thank you very much, was just what I needed. Now I understand better the pattern MVVM.

Answer (score 2):

This works for Silverlight so it should work on WPF (or at least it should with minor modifications)

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
<i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
<cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding MouseCommand, PassEventArgsToCommand="True", CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
</i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Comment: You forgot to mention that this uses Blend

Answer (score 0):

You can find **XCommand** open source codeplex wpf extention project here, [xcommand.codeplex.com](http://xcommand.codeplex.com), this allows you to bind Command and CommandParameter of any events like MouseMove, MouseLeftButtonDown to any UI elements that inherits from WPF UIElement.

You can find windows store 8 application and windows desktop application version of class libraries here. You want WPFXCommand that deals with WPF desktop application.
Here, how it works.
Add **WPFXCommand.dll** as reference to your desire project.

Add the namespace on your xaml file as below:

```
xmlns:XCmd="clr-namespace:WPFXCommand;assembly=WPFXCommand"
```

Now, you can bind ***Command*** and ***CommandParameter*** to any available events on any UI elements inherit from WPF UIElement as below:

```
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Margin="20,30,20,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="80" x:Name="XTextBlock"
               Foreground="{Binding FgColor, Mode=TwoWay}"
               XCmd:MouseMove.Command="{Binding TextBlockPointerMovedCommand}"
               XCmd:MouseLeftButtonDown.Command="{Binding TextBlockPointerPressedCommand}"
               XCmd:MouseLeave.Command="{Binding TextBlockPointerExitedCommand}"    
               Text="{Binding Description, Mode=TwoWay}">
        </TextBlock>
        <Grid Grid.Column="1" Background="{Binding BgColor, Mode=TwoWay}"
              XCmd:MouseMove.Command="{Binding GridPointerMovedCommand}" 
              XCmd:MouseMove.CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=XTextBlock, Path=Text}"
              XCmd:MouseLeftButtonDown.Command="{Binding GridPointerPressedCommand}"
              XCmd:MouseLeftButtonDown.CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=XTextBlock, Path=Text}"
              >
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

Hope this will help you to get rid of event based code behind.