# How to bind mousedouble click command in mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have listview and I want to have show new window when someone double click in any position. But I have mvvm application and I don't want to have any function in code behind of xaml file, like this: [How to bind a Command to double-click on a row in DataGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808616/how-to-bind-a-command-to-double-click-on-a-row-in-datagrid) and many other samples like this. I want to have method in viewmodel file and bind it like this:

```
<ListView ... MouseDoubleClick="{Binding myfunction}">
```

Thanks

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785685/wpf-and-mvvm-binding-events) for an MVVM example for Mouse events.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is a working example of a method to trigger a command (In the ViewModel) based on the clicked item in a list. The command in the ViewModel will get the "clicked" item as its parameter.

I'm using the Textblock.InputBindings and that might be part of the *Blend SDK* linked by Blachshma, but you will not need any other DLLs for this to work.

In my example the ViewModel is bound to the DataContext of the UserControl, that is why I need to use the *RelativeSource FindAncestor* to find the ViewModel from my TextBlock.

**Edit**:
Fixed the width problem by binding the *Width* of the *TextBlock* to the *ActualWidth* of the *ListBox*.

<del>Just **one** problem, the double click will only work when you click inside the text in the textblock even if the list itself is much wider.</del>

```
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Model.TablesView}"   Grid.Row="1" 
              SelectedItem="{Binding Model.SelectedTable, Mode=TwoWay}"  >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=.}" 
                   Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, 
                             RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}}" >
                    <TextBlock.InputBindings>
                        <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftDoubleClick" Command="{Binding DataContext.MoveItemRightCommand,
                                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                                        AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
                                      CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                    </TextBlock.InputBindings>
                </TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Answer (score 18):

You can use [Attached Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.asp) to bind any event you want.

For `MouseDoubleClick`:

```
namespace Behavior
{
public class MouseDoubleClick
{
    public static DependencyProperty CommandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Command",
        typeof(ICommand),
        typeof(MouseDoubleClick),
        new UIPropertyMetadata(CommandChanged));

    public static DependencyProperty CommandParameterProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("CommandParameter",
                                            typeof(object),
                                            typeof(MouseDoubleClick),
                                            new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    public static void SetCommand(DependencyObject target, ICommand value)
    {
        target.SetValue(CommandProperty, value);
    }

    public static void SetCommandParameter(DependencyObject target, object value)
    {
        target.SetValue(CommandParameterProperty, value);
    }
    public static object GetCommandParameter(DependencyObject target)
    {
        return target.GetValue(CommandParameterProperty);
    }
    private static void CommandChanged(DependencyObject target, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Control control = target as Control;
        if (control != null)
        {
            if ((e.NewValue != null) && (e.OldValue == null))
            {
                control.MouseDoubleClick += OnMouseDoubleClick;
            }
            else if ((e.NewValue == null) && (e.OldValue != null))
            {
                control.MouseDoubleClick -= OnMouseDoubleClick;
            }
        }
    }
    private static void OnMouseDoubleClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Control control = sender as Control;
        ICommand command = (ICommand)control.GetValue(CommandProperty);
        object commandParameter = control.GetValue(CommandParameterProperty);
        command.Execute(commandParameter);
    }
}
}
```

And in Xaml:

```
 <ListBox Behavior:MouseDoubleClick.Command="{Binding ....}"
          Behavior:MouseDoubleClick.CommandParameter="{Binding ....}"/>
```

Answer (score 13):

The easiest way to do this is to use `System.Windows.Interactivity` and `Microsoft.Expression.Interactions` (both freely available through the [Blend SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10801))

So start by adding the following namespaces to your view

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
```

Next, catch the DoubleClick event and pass it to the command:

```
<ListView ..... >
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
            <local:EventToCommand Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=DataContext.myfunction}" />
         </i:EventTrigger
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ListView>
```

Note: The `EventToCommand` used is the one from the [MVVM Light Toolkit](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/) and can be downloaded [here](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/b922e8ccf674#GalaSoft.MvvmLight/GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras%20(NET4)/Command/EventToCommandVS10.cs).
What it does is execute the command (`myFunction`) as soon as the event is triggered.

This is based on the assumption that the `myFunction` command is in the DataContext which the ListView users. Otherwise, modify the binding of the EventToCommand to wherever the command is.

Comment: I added a reference to Microsoft.Expression.Interactions.dll and now the build has an error saying this dll is not supported in a WPF project. VS 2013.

Comment: How to find that what are the valid events names available like EventName="MouseDoubleClick" you used? As it does not gives intellisense.